# How to list only folders inside jar using jar cmmand similar to jar -tvf will give all files and directory?

Tags: java, jar

I have jar containing different folder, sub-folder and files. 
To list and view the content of the jar i can use `jar -tvf jar_name`.
Is there any way jar -tvf or similar other command which will list only directory inside content of jar.

I am seeing jar have following option but other than `-t`, I cant find which can help to list files or folder specifically.Not all in once with `-t` option.

```
jar Options:
    -c  create new archive
    -t  list table of contents for archive
    -x  extract named (or all) files from archive
    -u  update existing archive
    -v  generate verbose output on standard output
    -f  specify archive file name
    -m  include manifest information from specified manifest file
    -e  specify application entry point for stand-alone application
        bundled into an executable jar file
    -0  store only; use no ZIP compression
    -M  do not create a manifest file for the entries
    -i  generate index information for the specified jar files
    -C  change to the specified directory and include the following file
```

I need to load the jar files and display the folder and files in the tree structure. What could be the best approach implement such logic.

Comment: Do you want to display it with java or only command line?

Comment: I wanted use that features in shell script and bat files.

Comment: I have edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks it work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command line(Linux);

```
jar tf JAR_PATH | grep ".*/$"
```

Java code to take directories in a jar file;

```
try {
    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(JAR_PATH);
    Enumeration<JarEntry> paths = jarFile.entries();
    while (paths.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry path = paths.nextElement();
        if (path.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(path.getName());
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jar is a zip file. Use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/196778) . Or programatically [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11468214/1737819) or this [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6510636/1737819)

**Get a list of files [(see docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html) and grep those lines that end with "\" <-- you will get a list of directories.**